# How to get the color of a window's frame?

Tags: windows, qt, styles

I'm trying to read the color of a window's border (frame) of a regular window.

It seems that `window->palette().color(QPalette::XXXX)` would do it, but what's `XXXX`? or is it not possible with palette? If so, how?

Comment: Change frame for "the title bar" (and the re-sizing border on Windows), sorry for the imprecision!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use it the native [`GetSysColorBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
QColor getWindowFrameColor() {
    // This is the only way to detect that a given color is supported
    HBRUSH brush = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER);
    if (brush) {
        DWORD color = GetSysColor(COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER);
        return QColor(GetRValue(color), GetGValue(color), GetBValue(color));
        // calling DeleteObject(brush) is unnecessary, but would be harmless
    }
    return QColor();
}
```

I've searched the Qt sources for `COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER`, and the only other way to retrieve it would be by running some custom javascript code on WebKit.

Comment: But that, being native, would be system dependent. I was searching something portable, thanks!

Comment: @Juan: On X-windows-based platforms, there's simply no general way of getting this information. On OS X, there is no notion of a window frame color. The theming mechanism doesn't just have a "color" value for that. So what portability exactly do you expect from something that's supported only on **one** of the three most popular desktop platforms out there?

Comment: @Juan: Basically, it *is* portable - to the only platform where this kind of information is available on.

Comment: You're right Kuba, I didn't stop to think in detail and see that the only platform making sense is windows.